# What is the correct way to get a Hadoop FileSystem object that can be used for reading from/writing to HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

What is the correct way to create a FileSystem object that can be used for reading from/writing to HDFS? In some examples I've found, they do something like this:

```
final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));

final FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

From looking at the documentation for the Configuration class, it looks like the properties from core-site.xml are automatically loaded when the object is created if that file is on the classpath, so there is no need to set it again.

I haven't found anything that says why adding hdfs-site.xml would be required, and it seems to work fine without it.

Would it be safe to just put core-site.xml on the classpath and skip hdfs-site.xml, or should I be setting both like I've seen in the examples? In what cases would the properties from hdfs-site.xml be required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileSystem` needs only one configuration key to successfully connect to HDFS. Previously it was `fs.default.name`. From `yarn` onward it's changed to `fs.defaultFS`. So the following snippet is sufficient for the connection.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set(key, "hdfs://host:port");  // where key="fs.default.name"|"fs.defaultFS"

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

**Tip :** Check the `core-site.xml` which key exists. Set the same value associated with it in `conf`. If the machine from where you are running the code doesn't have the host name mapping, put the its IP. In `mapR` cluster value will have prefix like `maprfs://`.

Comment: Since Configuration automatically loads the properties from core-site.xml in its constructor, and core-site.xml should contain fs.defaultFS, I shouldn't need to set any properties as long as it's on the classpath, correct?

Comment: You are damn right. My point is that you can achieve the same only setting one key to `conf` without adding those files to classpath or to conf. However, you will need them when submitting MR jobs.

Answer (score 1):

For the question:

> Would it be safe to just put core-site.xml on the classpath and skip hdfs-site.xml, or should I be setting both like I've seen in the examples? In what cases would the properties from hdfs-site.xml be required?

I do an experiment: if you are using **CDH**  (Cloudera's Distribution Including Apache Hadoop, my version is Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.11.1), it's not safe to use **core-site.xml** only.It will throw Exception：

`Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException`

And if you add **hdfs-site.xml**, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a block of code from one of my projects for building a `Configuration` usable for HBase, HDFS and map-reduce.  Notice that `addResource` will search the active classpath for the resources entries you name.

```
HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(config);
config.addResource("mapred-default.xml");
config.addResource("mapred-site.xml");
```

My classpath definitely includes the directories housing `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, and `hbase-site.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually already have this working. I was more interested in finding the minimum files I need for accessing HDFS, in what cases I'd need something different, and why.

There doesn't seem to be much documentation for this.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  I've found that configurations containing just `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` are enough for this.