# unable to connect to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to create a directory using hdfs, my Hadoop cluster is not running on localhost, rather it's running on a different network. Please tell me how to connect correctly. I am using the following code to connect to hdfs:

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


    public class HadoopJava {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            HadoopJava hadoopJava = new HadoopJava();
            hadoopJava.mkdir("/home/anoop/javamkdir");
        }


        public void mkdir(String directory) throws IOException {

            Configuration obj = new Configuration();
            obj.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://10.111.214.124:50070");

            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(obj);
            Path path = new Path(directory);
            fs.mkdirs(path);
            System.out.println("created");
            fs.close();

        }
    }
```

The error trace is as follows:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:886)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:783)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:365)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2086)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2055)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2031)
>         at HadoopJava.copyfileFromHDFSToLOCAL(HadoopJava.java:74)
>         at HadoopJava.main(HadoopJava.java:29)

Comment: what exception it throws ? Again which version of Hadoop you are using ?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536886/what-is-the-correct-way-to-get-a-hadoop-filesystem-object-that-can-be-used-for-r

Comment: Please provide the error message along with your conf files. Additionally, are you running it via the command line or within an IDE?

Comment: I am running it in eclipse.